# Running jobs concurrently with multiple steps

Tags: nextflow

I need to run 10,000 pipelines, each consisting of 5 steps (processes)

Another requirement is that I want to run about 300 concurrently. Meaning, I want 300 to start, then for each pipeline that finished the 5 steps, I want to start a new pipeline. I couldn't find how to do it using channels.

Some initial thoughts:
start by splitting the 10,000 channel to buffers of 300 items.
But it doesn't help with starting a new one when one ends...

```
proteins = Channel.fromPath( '/some/path/*.fa' ).buffer( size: 300 )

process A {
  input:
  file query_file from proteins

  output:
}
process B {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve *approximately* what you want using the following in your `nextflow.config`:

```
process {

    maxForks = 300
}

executor {

    queueSize = 300
}
```

- The [maxForks](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#maxforks) directive sets the maximum number of process instances that can be executed in parallel. By setting this value in your nextflow.config, we ensure it is blanket applied to each of your five processes. If you have other processes that you don't want covered by this directive, you can of course use one or more [process selectors](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors) to select the processes you want to limit this configuration to. Alternatively, just add the directive to each of your five process definitions.
- The [executor](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-executor) `queueSize` just defines the number of tasks the executor will handle in parallel.

This of course won't guarantee the completion of a chunk of five processes before starting a new chunk, but that usually isn't much of a concern.

Comment: I see, but I'm afraid that when the first process ends, instead of the second step, there will be another instance of the first process. I'll test how it works exactly...

Comment: @MosheShaham Can I ask why is that an issue? Usually the order of execution doesn't matter, since you need all jobs complete anyway.